# how to change <input> type-text to type-date in django form

Tags: django

I want to apply bootstrap for forms, but in the input "date" tag the "type" is defined as "text".
model:

```
class AdmissionForm(forms.Form):
date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(
attrs={
'class': 'form-control'
}
))
def save(self):
    new_admission = Admission.objects.create(
    date = self.cleaned_data['date'],)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is another solution now. But I couldn't find one a while back and I used [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/) package. It's really easy and nice

Comment: how to change language:  class AdmissionForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(
        widget=DatePickerInput(format='%m/%d/%Y')
    )

Comment: what language? Do you mean the calendar type

Comment: yes, Russian calendar, I tried changing to "locale": "ru" but it didn’t work